# Get Common data from two different table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have 2 table With same column name (Id,FName, LName,DOB,Type,Contact, Add).

Now I want to get all data as a separate row which have same FName, LName and DOB from both table as order by Fname .

I try to use intersect and Union but not work for me.

```
  Select * from #t1 where FirstName in (select FirstName from #t2 ) and LastName in  (select LastName from #t2 ) and DateOfBirth in (select DateOfBirth from #t2 ) 
 UNION
Select * from #t2 where FirstName in (select FirstName from #t1 ) and LastName in  (select LastName from #t1 ) and DateOfBirth in (select DateOfBirth from #t1 )      order by FirstName ,LastName
```

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What is it tha happens to make you say this? You know that `UNION` on it's own performs a `GROUP BY` operation, right? If you want ALL rows regrardless of duplication use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: it does not work in my case becoz it check FirstName in all data of T2 and same for Lastname and Dob.

Comment: OK, well looks like Nithesh has provided a suitable answer before I could finish typing. But be careful of tagging multiple DB platforms - not all syntax is common across all platforms (although fine in this case).

Comment: @Steve Pettifer : Still not get proper solution. please read my comment on Nilesh post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it I think but I'm sure there's a more succinct way...

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 
    ON T2.FirstName = T1.FirstName
    AND T2.LastName = T1.LastName
    AND T2.DateOfBirth = T1.DateOfBirth
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.*
FROM T2
INNER JOIN T1 
    ON T1.FirstName = T2.FirstName
    AND T1.LastName = T2.LastName
    AND T1.DateOfBirth = T2.DateOfBirth
```

Comment: No worries. I'm convinced there's a more compact way to do it, I'm just trying to work out what that is!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT T1.Id,
       T1.FName, 
       T1.LName,
       T1.DOB,
       T1.Type,
       T1.Contact,
       T1.Add
FROM #t1 T1 INNER JOIN #t2 T2
   ON  T1.FName=T2.FName
   AND T1.LName=T2.LName
   AND T1.dob=T2.dob
```

Comment: Sounds nearest what the OP wants I think.

Comment: what if contact, add and others fields have different data?

Comment: question says that `only same FName, LName and DOB `.

Comment: @user790454 : Now U get my question.what u say that I want data with two row with order by FirstName

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
Select a.*,b.* from #t1 a join #t2 b on (a.FName=b.FName and a.LName=b.LName and a.DOB=b.DOB)
```

Comment: Hi U use join and combine common data from both table as row but I want to get this data as two row

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is by aggregating after the `union`.  Then check that the values appear the requisite number of times:

```
select firstname, lastname, dob
from ((select firstname, lastname, dob, 't1' as which
       from #t1
      ) union all
      (select firstname, lastname, dob, 't2' as which
       from #t2
      )
     ) t
group by firstname, lastname, dob
having count(distinct which) = 2;
```

Comment: Hi This query display common data as a one row but I want to get both common data from both table I mean as two separate row with other column like Type, Contact and Add.